# How to change src to data-src in YouTube plugin?

Tags: javascript, src

I want to add `data-src` instead of `src` through javascript code. Please help me I have spent lots of time on it. Its realted to the lazy load concept.

```html
<iframe id="mbYTP_ut-background-video-hero" class="playerBox" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 1772.76px; height: 859px; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; margin-top: -330px; margin-left: -211.88px; transition-property: opacity; transition-duration: 1000ms;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KhzGSHNhnbI"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using jQuery. According to your Code, Example is given below.

At first take **src** value. Then add new attribute **data-src** and keep your **src** value in **data-src**. Then you can remove **src** if you need.

jQuery Part:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        /*Get value from src*/
        var get_src = $('#mbYTP_ut-background-video-hero').attr('src');

        /*Add new attribute data-src and put src value here*/
 $('#mbYTP_ut-background-video-hero').attr('data-src',get_src);

       /*Remove src here. If you don't need to remove src then comment below part */
 $('#mbYTP_ut-background-video-hero').removeAttr('src');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="mbYTP_ut-background-video-hero" class="playerBox" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 1772.76px; height: 859px; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; margin-top: -330px; margin-left: -211.88px; transition-property: opacity; transition-duration: 1000ms;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KhzGSHNhnbI"></iframe>
```